# What's Ban power level when he gets out of purgatory?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Supposedly purgatory's harsh conditions and Ban regeneration would make him to stay there for long, making him a lot stronger. What's ban power level when he gets out of purgatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ban's power hasn't been calculated after his exit from Purgatory.**

However, we can roughly estimate his power level. In the battle against Demon King!Meliodas, Ban manages to hold his own and fight him one-on-one for an extended period of time. On the other hand, Mael (whose power level is greater than 200 000, according to *chapter 279*) was effortlessly pushed back by Demon King!Meliodas in a previous assault.

We can thus conclude that post-Purgatory!Ban's power level goes **far above 200 000**.

Answer (score 0):

its around maybe 400'000 and I think that because ban after purgetory ban was a stunning asset to the battle against the demon king/meliodas